# Migration after using Xethron/migrations-generator laravel 5.6

Tags: migration, laravel-5.6

i have used the package Xethron/migrations-generator , for generate migration from existing database , he work well ! 
But after when i want to add a column to a table i have edit the corresponding migration file like that :

```
Schema::table('ville', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->double('lng')->nullable();
        $table->double('lat')->nullable();
    });
```

and do this command :

```
php artisan migrate
```

And i got this error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6hXl.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `php artisan migrate:refresh`